# Date format is switching month and day

Tags: excel, vba, date

Could you please someone can help me on how to change the date formatting cause i use the following code and instead of today's date it gives me august date. I mean it takes the date of my laptop (08-sep-2015) and it returns on the excel cell (09-Aug-2015).

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
'testing variable
'Dim LValue As String

'LValue = Format(#4/17/2004#, "Long Date")
'close testing variable

Me.tbDate = Date


'fill combobox


For Each cell In [cartridges]
    Me.cmbCartridges.AddItem cell
Next cell

End Sub
```

The part that i exclude form the code is a test i made for a solution i found over the internet.

Also the text box that i want to present the date has the following code

```
ssheet.Cells(nr, 1) = CDate(Me.tbDate)
```

Comment: What's your default system date format?  mm/dd/yyyy or dd/mm/yyyy  ?

Comment: This is most likely due to the system's date format (8th of September = 09/08/2015 in `mm/dd/yyyy`, but 8th of September = 08/09/2015 in `dd/mm/yyyy` format).  Try forcing the `Me.tbDate` to be text, `Me.tbDate = Text(me.tbDate,"mm/dd/yyyy")` (or whatever format).

Comment: yes but if i change {me.tbDate} in text then how it will aquire automatically the date from the laptop?

Comment: @BruceWayne he can force the correct date Format() to set it back to his system date instead of US date

Answer (score 1):

I found this and sorted my issue. Now everything its working like a charm.

```
Me.tbDate = Format(Date, "dd/mm/yyyy")
```

Comment: This doesn't really fix your issue long term, it is just a quick fix for now. I'd look into what Tim Williams said in his comment to see if you can resolve the issue as I think your systems date format and excels date format defaults might differ

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my issue with this code. I intentionally formated the cell the wrong way (excel default) and then formated it as I needed.

```
For j = 0 To LISTBOXNAME.ListCount - 1
LISTBOXNAME.List(j) = Format(DateValue(LISTBOXNAME.List(j)), "m/d/yyyy")
LISTBOXNAME.List(j) = Format(DateValue(LISTBOXNAME.List(j)), "dd.mm.yyyy")
Next j
```